# What is the correct way to export/import data using cassandra-loader/cassandra-unloader for YugaByte DB on a table with JSONB column(s)

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

I tried to use the steps described here https://docs.yugabyte.com/v1.1/manage/data-migration/cassandra/bulk-export/

`wget https://github.com/YugaByte/cassandra-loader/releases/download/v0.0.27-yb-2/cassandra-loader

wget https://github.com/YugaByte/cassandra-loader/releases/download/v0.0.27-yb-2/cassandra-unloader
chmod a+x cassandra-unloader
chmod a+x cassandra-loader`

Since above tools are JVM based, installed open jdk
`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`

Then exported the rows using:

`% cd /home/yugabyte/entity
% ./cassandra-unloader  -schema "my_ksp.my_table(id,type,details)"  -host <tserver-ip> -f export.csv -numThreads 3
Total rows retrieved: 10000`

Here `details` is a JSONB column. Next, I create a new table `my_table_new` in the same cluster, and try to load this data into

`./cassandra-loader  -schema "my_ksp.my_table_new(id,type,details)"  -host <tserver-ip> -f /home/yugabyte/entity -numThreads 3  -progressRate 200000 -numFutures 256 -rate 5000 -queryTimeout 65`

But get errors of the form:
`Row has different number of fields (12) than expected (3)`

It looks like the default delimiter “,” in the CSV file is causing the issue, since the JSONB data in the CSV file also has commas.

As an alternative tried passing `-delim “\t”` to cassandra-unloader-- but that seems to insert two characters “\” and “t” and not the single-tab character. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that, with cassandra-unloader/cassandra-loader, the default delimiter (",") doesn't work in the presence of YCQL JSONB columns in Yugabyte DB.

Regarding:

<< As an alternative tried passing -delim “\t” to cassandra-unloader-- but that seems to insert two characters “\” and “t” and not the single-tab character. Is that expected? >>

Using tab as the delimiter character should work right. But the unix shell needs some escaping to pass "\t" correctly to the program.  Please see: https://superuser.com/questions/362235/how-do-i-enter-a-literal-tab-character-in-a-bash-shell

Use:
`-delim $'\t'`
instead of
`-delim "\t"`

So for example for the export, try:

`./cassandra-unloader  -schema "my_ksp.my_table(id,type,details)"  -host <tserver-ip> -f export.csv -numThreads 3 -delim $'\t'`

and for the import, try:

`./cassandra-loader  -schema "my_ksp.my_table_new(id,type,details)"  -host <tserver-ip> -f /home/yugabyte/entity -numThreads 3  -progressRate 200000 -numFutures 256 -rate 5000 -queryTimeout 65 -delim $'\t'`